# Trying to show all members of guild by bot, Discord JS

Tags: discord.js

Thats' my "final" code that doesn't work at all and showing me

> **TypeError: list.members is not iterable**.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

```
const list = bot.guilds.cache.get(guild_id); 
            for(member of list.members){
                console.log(member.user.username);
            }
```

Where bot is a Discord.Client()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the `members` `cache` in order to get the collection and loop through it.

```js
const list = bot.guilds.cache.get(guild_id); 
for(member of list.members.cache){
    console.log(member.user.username);
}
```

Comment: It only returns 2 members out of 5 in a test server. Me and the Bot.

Comment: @Beyondo That's because you did not setup your Privileged Gateway Intents, you can change them in the Bot tab of your Application's page. In this case, you'd have to enable the Server Members Intent.

Comment: Woow. You actually saved me! Because it got me so confused for a long while... thank you.